# Batch script to close desired Command Prompt windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

First, I have a script that starts 4 java programs:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\work\clientes\loremIpsum\loremIpsum\loremIpsum\target"
start "BROKER" java -jar loremIpsum-broker.jar

cd "C:\work\clientes\loremIpsum\loremIpsum\loremIpsum-virtual-devices-engine\target"
start "VIRTUAL-DEVICES-ENGINE" java -jar loremIpsum-virtual-devices-engine.jar

cd "C:\work\clientes\loremIpsum\loremIpsum\loremIpsum-websocket\target"
start "WEBSOCKET" java -jar loremIpsum-websocket.jar

cd "C:\work\clientes\loremIpsum\loremIpsum-loremIpsum\dandelion-workflow-engine\target"
start "WORKFLOW-ENGINE" java -jar loremIpsum-workflow-engine.jar
exit
```

I want to make a script that closes only these 4. I´ve tried with wmic:

```
@echo off
wmic process where "name like '%java%'" delete
exit
```

But I don't want it to close my other java aplications, only these 4

Comment: Can't you get the process IDs and do a taskkill of them?

Comment: How could I do that in a script?

Comment: `tasklist`? (Give it a try)

Comment: Wondering if the process shows the path to the jar when you use the `get commandline` option.  `wmic process where "name like '%java%'" get caption,processid,commandline` . I know nothing about java so I am just wondering what outputs with that command.

Comment: Or maybe this: `wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like 'loremIpsum-broker.jar%'" Call Terminate`

Comment: Not a solution, but you should change `cd ...` to `cd /D ...`...

Comment: Following on from the last comment by @Squashman, the most likely unique and known commandline, would be its ending, e.g. `-broker.jar`. So the wildcard, `%` should represent the beginning of the commandline, i.e. `%-broker.jar`, _(doubled in a batch file `%%-broker.jar`)_ You would therefore use the following: `WMIC Process Where "CommandLine Like '%%-broker.jar'" Call Terminate`. I would suspect however that `java.exe` actually passes the initial command through a separate instance of `cmd.exe`, opening it in another window, which could be problematic, unless we knew what command it passed!

Comment: If the java command actually opens in a new `cmd.exe` window, with the window title you've stipulated, `BROKER`, you should be able to terminate it using `TaskKill`. Perhaps something like this: `TaskKill /F /FI "WindowTitle Eq BROKER" /T >Nul`.

Comment: @Compo It works, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely unique and known commandline, would be its ending, e.g. `-broker.jar`. So the wildcard, `%` should represent the beginning of the commandline, i.e. `%-broker.jar`, *(doubled in a batch file `%%-broker.jar`)*. You would therefore use the following:

```bat
WMIC Process Where "CommandLine Like '%%-broker.jar'" Call Terminate
```

I would suspect however that `java.exe` actually passes the initial command through a separate instance of `cmd.exe`, opening it in another window, which could be problematic, *unless we knew what command it passed!*

If the `java` command actually opens in a new `cmd.exe` window, with the window title you've stipulated, `BROKER`, you should be able to terminate it using `TaskKill`. Perhaps something like this:

```bat
TaskKill /F /FI "WindowTitle Eq BROKER" /T >Nul
```